# Is there a Ruby on Rails generate migration statement to change "description" from string to text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

It looks like `string` is limited to 256 characters and `text` is usually 65536 characters.

I tried

```
ruby script/generate migration change_description_to_text description:text
```

but the `up` and `down` in the migration file generated are both empty?  Is there a way to generate this migration automatically?

If added manually using a `remove_column` and an `add_column`, will all the old data be removed for the column?

Answer (score 2):

see the way of using migration itself wrong,

because you are changing the description string into text but u didnt specify which table so

use as following method.

```
ruby script/generate migration change_description_string_to_text
```

in migration,

```
def self.up
    change_column :user, :description, :text
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :user, :description, :string
  end
```